# How can I search through fish completions?

Tags: autocomplete, fish

I've noticed that sometimes, when there are multiple completion options, I get something like an input field, beneath the command line, where I can type and filter the completions. I'm not sure how I triggered it. Is there a key combination that I can press so that I have it available on demand?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To enter search mode directly, you can press shift-tab. You can also press tab until the highlight is in the pager, and then just start typing: that triggers searching too.

*Update March 2020*: This changed in fish 3.0 [here](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/2249). There's now two ways to reveal the completion search:

- Press `ctrl s` to toggle the search field while the pager is active
- Press `shift tab` instead of `tab` to trigger completions with the search field shown immediately

These correspond to `pager-toggle-search` and `complete-and-search` key bindings.

Comment: Has this changed since fish 3.1? Because not it doesn't seem to work. I also have oh-my-fish installed maybe that's changing it. Is there a way to change this or can that not interfere? Would love to be able to use it again, ATM typing anything after tabbing all the way to pager just appends that after the selected autocomplete.

Comment: Is there a way to have the previous behavior in new fish? I can never get it to work with `shift tab`. How can I set it back to start search when I have first options selected and I start typing. Thanks for your hard work! I really love this shell ❤️

Comment: As of fish 3.0 typing always appends to the commandline; there's no way to have it trigger searching. Sorry :/